# Removing an icon on statusbar

Tags: app-icons

[image: the screenshot]

How can I get rid of the sun icon on the top left of the statusbar???

I've checked my wether apps, and it doesn't belong to them.

Comment: That seems to be a notification icon. Generally, if you pull down the notification bar, and long-press on the representative notification, the AppInfo will lead you to the correct app it is derived from, allowing you to close it, or modify its settings for notifications.

Comment: It would seem to be from a weather related application, do you have weather stats/info displaying in the notification area when you swipe down the notification bar?

Comment: @wbogacz This won't be possible with Android 5.0 and above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Samsung and I presume you're on version 6.0, go to Settings > Notifications and toggle off All Apps. Now activate the notification for every app, one by one. This way you may find which one is responsible for the sun icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Accuweather installed, you have to go into the app's Settings, On-going Notification, and turn that off.